# Set variable from an array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The dump of the following array is:

```
$quest_all = $qwinners->pluck('id', 'qcounter')->toArray();
```

```
array(2) { [60]=> int(116) [50]=> int(117) }
```

As shown above, the key is 60 and 50 (which is qcounter), while the value is 116 and 117 (which is id).

I'm trying to assign the qcounter to a variable as follows, but with a fixed index, such as 0,1,2,3 .. etc :

```
$qcounter1= $quest_all[0];
$qcounter2= $quest_all[1];
```

And the same with id :

```
$id1= $quest_all[0];
$id2= $quest_all[1];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question a bit more. What is the actual requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset array keys, use [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php).
To get array keys, use [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php):

```
$quest_all = $qwinners->pluck('id', 'qcounter')->toArray();
$quest_all_keys = array_keys($quest_all);
$quest_all_values = array_values($quest_all);
```

Or simply use `foreach()`:

```
$keys = [];
$values = [];
foreach($quest_all as $key => $value){
    $keys[] = $key;
    $values[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: But array_values has replaced the qcounter. How can I still keep both "id" and "qcounter" in the array to then assign them to variables ?

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:
One way is:
`array_values($quest_all);` will give you an array of all Ids
`array_keys($quest_all);` will give an array of all qcounters and respective indexes for qcounter and ids will be the same.

Other way, First get all qcounters only from collection:

```
$quest_all = $qwinners->pluck('qcounter')->toArray();
$qcounter1= $quest_all[0];
$qcounter2= $quest_all[1];
    ...
    and so on
```

Then get all `ids`

```
$quest_all = $qwinners->pluck('id')->toArray();
$id1= $quest_all[0];
$id2= $quest_all[1];
    ...
and so on
```

You can also use `foreach` to iterate through the result array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want variable names incrementing when you could have an array instead but if you don't mind an underscore, '_' in the name and them starting at 0 index you can use `extract` to create these variables. (As an exercise)

```
$quest_all = ...;

$count = extract(array_keys($quest_all), EXTRA_PREFIX_ALL, 'qcounter');
extract(array_values($quest_all), EXTRA_PREFIX_ALL, 'id');
// $qcounter_0 $qcounter_1
// $id_0 $id_1


for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo ${'qcounter_'. $i} .' is '. ${'id_'. $i} ."\n";
}
```

It would probably be easier to just have the 2 arrays:

```
$keys = array_keys($quest_all);
$values = array_values($quest_all);
```